# How to create a document wide table style for border

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to separate table content and table style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/how-to-separate-table-content-and-table-style)

is it possible to create a document wide table setting for how table border are applied for each table?

I want to have the first table line have bold borders on top and bottom and the last row of a table should have a bold border at the bottom.
As i do not want to specify all of this for each table, is there a way to do it one?

```
====================
row 1
====================
row 2
--------------------
row ..
------------------
row n
===================
```

Legend:

"==" -> bold border

"--" -> normal border

Comment: very closely related: [how-to-separate-table-content-and-table-style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/how-to-separate-table-content-and-table-style)

Answer (score 0):

Below, I have defined a `myTabular` environment that you can use. It takes two parameters: the first is the usual parameter for `tabular` to specify the alignment, the second is the header row.  So specifying something such as:

```
\begin{MyTabular}{c c}{Header 1 & Header 1}
    1.234  & 2.345\\\hline
    4.5678 & 5.123\\
\end{MyTabular}
```

produces:

[image]

### References:

- This thick horizontal rule is from [How can I reproduce this table with thick lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41758/how-can-i-reproduce-this-table-with-thick-lines)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41758/how-can-i-reproduce-this-table-with-thick-lines
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{MyTabular}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
    \thickhline#2\\\thickhline%
}{%
    \thickhline%
    \end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{MyTabular}{c c}{Header 1 & Header 1}
    1.234  & 2.345\\\hline
    4.5678 & 5.123\\
\end{MyTabular}
\end{document}
```