# How to define a table in documentclass?

Tags: tables, document-classes, tabularx, documentclass-writing

Consider a simple table in the document:

```
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
```

How we can define this table within the `documentclass` as users only put the values of each cell. I mean how to set variables in the `documentclass`, as we have, for example, for sections:

```
\section*{Section Header}
Section body
```

How to define the table as users can fill the variable in the documents as something like:

```
\table{header1,header2,header3}
row1: cell1, cell2, cell3
...
```

Comment: Are *all* the tables supposed to be like that? And where's the advantage in inputting the table in that way?

Comment: Yes, consider that all tables have the same number of columns. The advantage is designing the table with additional packages like `tikz` the end user does not mess with a long list of codes; just put what he has. I think this is the main purpose of `documentsclass`es in general (to keep users from mess of codes).

Comment: @Ali To some extent, but the `tablular` environment is part of the standard LaTeX kernel. As such, _any_ LaTeX user should be okay with `tablular`. All you will do with your idea is break things!

Comment: @JosephWright But sometimes the `tabular` is mixed with less known packages for better design. In any case, there is no downside (if there's no advantage) for pulling the table codes into `documentsclass` to keep the main document tidy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define this environment

```
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\newenvironment{commontabular}[3]
  {\begin{tabular}{lcr}
   \toprule
   \bfseries #1 & \bfseries #2 & \bfseries #3 \\
   \midrule}
  {\bottomrule
   \end{tabular}}
```

and then tell users to input their tables as

```
\begin{commontabular}{header1}{header2}{header3}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{commontabular}
```

There's no point in using a non standard syntax for tables, as this hinders code reusability.

But I see no point in providing such shortcuts either.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve what you want using `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` However, we must remember that both of these commands can accept at *most* 9 arguments.

So, borrowing the idea from Yiannis in

[Definitive guide to trivlists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47204/definitive-guide-to-trivlists)

we have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{mytabular}
  {\trivlist\item
   \tabular{lcr}}
  {\endtabular\endtrivlist}

\newcommand{\row}[3]{#1&#2&#3\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}
   \row{1}{2}{3}
   \row{4}{5}{6}
   \row{7}{8}{9}
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

You might also like to look at

[How to separate table content and table style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/how-to-separate-table-content-and-table-style)