# Styling  lots of tables

Tags: tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to separate table content and table style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13744/how-to-separate-table-content-and-table-style)

I am writing a document that include more than 50 tables. The tables can be divided into 5 groups with similar styles.

How can I neatly, centrally and systematically style each group of tables?
Is there any styling method similar to CSS?