# Creating variables with index (using counters)

Tags: counters, loops

Is there a way to add an index to a command? For example:

```
\newcounter{count}
\loop<condition>
  \def\var\Roman{count}{some data}
\repeat
```

The `\var\Roman{count}` should become the variable `\varI`, `\varII`, `\varIII` and so on.

Background: I need to get some data from external files and store it into variables (which I will later use to create a document). Normally every `\varI` should be the same as every `\varII`, but I need to check whether it really is the case or not. If not I should return a warning or error.

---

Solution for the first problem is in the comments, but I have a second problem.

Suppose I wrote this:

```
\newcommand\addindex[3]{  % #1 as name of var, #2 as index and #3 as content
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\Roman{#2}\endcsname{#3}  % thanks to egreg
}

\newcounter{count}
\loop\unless\ifnum\value{count}=5
  \stepcounter{count}
  \addindex{var}{count}{\arabic{count}}
\repeat
```

All `\var<index>` have now as value 5, because they are defined as `\arabic{count}`, and not their value at the moment. Adding `\expandafter` before `\arabic{count}` does not seem to work for some reason...

Comment: `\@namedef{var\romannumeral\c@count}{some data}`

Comment: Or `\expandafter\def\csname var\Roman{count}\endcsname{...}`

Comment: Thanks again egreg, I'm starting to like you `:p` @DavidCarlisle: thanks, but in that way I have to use TeX counters instead of LaTeX counters. I prefer the LaTeX way `:)`

Comment: Also, is there a way to read them again using another loop? I can't seem to find out how for the moment...

Comment: Figured it out, I could just use the `\csname` environment again `:)`

Comment: @Didii well yes and no, `\c@count` is the latex counter defined as in your question with `\newcounter{count}` just accessed differently. It's the same as `\roman{count}` except that it saves an expansion and 7 tokens (which probably mattered more in 1990 than it does now:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: makes sense `:)` I do have a problem now with the `\def`, for some reason I can't expand what I write as `some data`. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Didii Use `\edef` instead of `\def` after `\expandafter`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, never heard of that command before `:)`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63573/separate-style-and-content-in-table for an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method is quite simple, but I add a trick that can be useful in your application:

```
\newcounter{tempcount} % for temporary usage

\newcommand\addindex[4][]{% #2 as name of var, #3 as index and #4 as content
  \csname#1def\expandafter\endcsname\csname #2\Roman{#3}\endcsname{#4}%
}
```

Now we want to define `\varI`, `\varII`, `\varIII` and `\varIV` to expand to `some text`:

```
\setcounter{tempcount}{0}

\loop\ifnum\value{tempcount}<4
  \stepcounter{tempcount}
  \addindex{var}{tempcount}{some text}
\repeat
```

If instead you want that `\varI` expands to `1` and so on, here's the role of the optional argument:

```
\setcounter{tempcount}{0}

\loop\ifnum\value{tempcount}<4
  \stepcounter{tempcount}
  \addindex[e]{var}{tempcount}{\arabic{tempcount}}
\repeat
```

By passing `e` as the optional argument, what's executed is `\csname edef\endcsname`, that is `\edef` that expands completely the replacement text before doing the definition. With no optional argument only `\def` is used.

A more efficient definition would be of `\vari`, `\varii` and so on (with lowercase roman numbers):

```
\newcommand\addindex[4][]{% #2 as name of var, #3 as index and #4 as content
  \csname#1def\expandafter\endcsname\csname #2\roman{#3}\endcsname{#4}%
}
```

It's more efficient because `\Roman{tempcount}` has to scan each character in the expansion of `\roman{tempcount}` and change it to its uppercase counterpart, while `\roman{tempcount}` expands to `\romannumeral\c@tempcount` using the TeX primitive `\romannumeral`, which is quite fast.

Comment: Why is the `\expandafter` needed? I'm currently searching what it **exactly** does, but can't seem to find it easily..

Comment: The `\expandafter` last before `\endcsname` is necessary so that the following `\csname` is processed *before* TeX forms the token `\def` or `\edef`. So when the counter's value is 1, for instance, what TeX will see is `\def\varI`. Without the `\expandafter` it would see `\def\csname varI\endcsname` which is wrong.

Comment: I finally found a question which answers that `:)`. Thanks.