# Default Table Style

Tags: tables, formatting

How can I create a default `table style`, which remains throughout the course of my document, lets say, for example, I want grid-lines and a gray shading behind the header-row, without having to explicitly format every table instance to this standard, is it possible to define these styling flavors in the preamble to affect all tables, in effect, on a global basis?

Comment: The `pgfplotstable` package can do this.

Comment: The first linked question in the Related section is really related: [How to separate table content and table style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13744)

Comment: To ADP: could we close this as a duplicate of @Qrrbrbirlbel link- there's a few different solutions, one of which uses `pgfplotstable` package with complete MWEs.... let us know if it is different, and if so, it might be nice to elaborate a little :)

Comment: Just close it off, Qrrbrbirbel's like is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Try the package [`cals`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals). I wrote it with a similar need in mind.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX. Would you consider adding your information to our package maintainers database? http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here

Comment: Yes, I think it's good to be listed. But I have no rights to edit the list and see no obvious way to submit the data. Would you please do it for me?
cals
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals
Oleg Parashchenko
https://github.com/olpa/tex/tree/master/cals

Comment: @olpa: I've added the entry; I think now you should have enough rep to propose edits on meta.